# Customize Twitter Bootstrap Classnames

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, class, twitter-bootstrap-3, prefix, classname

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Above link, customizes Bootstrap's components, Less variables, and jQuery plugins to get your very own version.

I am wondering if it's possible to customize bootstrap by adding prefixes to it's classes, for example:

```
".container" = ".myid_container"
".btn-group" = ".myid_btn-group"
```

Comment: You can fairly easily write a CSS postprocessor (using something like [postcss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss)) to do this sort of thing. The Bootstrap Customizer page itself can't do this. Note that you'll have to make corresponding changes to Bootstrap's JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

You can @extend bootstrap classes and call them whatever you want if you are using sass. Here is the info http://www.sitepoint.com/sass-semantically-extend-bootstrap/

But if you use plain bootstrap.css I'm not sure if there is a way to rename bootstrap classes except for renaming them in the file.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but this may help people coming here from search engines - you can do the following in scss to achieve the above:

```
// allows this file to use bootstrap classes and functions
@forward "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

.myid_container{
  @extend .container;
}

.myid_btn-group{
  @extend .btn-group;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just go to your bootstrap css file on any editor and then use "Find & Replace" (Ctrl + H in Notepad++) to replace all '.' with '.myid_'